# Custom URI Oauth2 + Spring security - REST API

Tags: rest, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

i need help to make a custom URI using Oauth2, i implemented one using something like this.

```
oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=restapp&client_secret=restapp&username=user123&password=pass123
```

but i want to pass all the data using headers, but i didn't found any example to how to do it.

is it possible? or recommendable? 
thank you very much.

EDIT: add my spring-security.xml

```
<import resource="/spring-config.xml" />    

<!-- This is default url to get a token from OAuth -->
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
      authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
    parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
                   after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<!-- This is where we tells spring security what URL should be protected 
and what roles have access to them -->
<http pattern="/api/prod/**" create-session="never"
      entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/prod/**" access="ROLE_APP" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>


<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>


<!-- Custom User details service which is provide the user data -->
<bean id="customAuthenticationProvider"
      class="com.system.rest.natura.resources.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider" />


<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
                        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" /> 

</authentication-manager>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
                        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />  

</authentication-manager>


<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="tokenStore"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

<bean id="tokenServices"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="1200" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
</bean>

<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
                       resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <!-- client -->
    <clientAuthenticationScheme>

    </clientAuthenticationScheme>
    <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
                  authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
                  authorities="ROLE_APP" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />

    <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
                  authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
                  secret="restapp" authorities="ROLE_APP" />

</oauth:client-details-service>

<sec:global-method-security
    pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put this line in **src/main/application.yml** ?

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
       clientAuthenticationScheme: header
```

**EDIT 1 :**

According to https://github.com/jirutka/spring-security-oauth-samples/blob/master/tonr/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/security.xml, in XML you must have something like this :

```
<oauth:resource id="facebook"
                type="authorization_code"
                client-id="233668646673605"
                client-secret="33b17e044ee6a4fa383f46ec6e28ea1d"
                authentication-scheme="query" 
                access-token-uri="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token"
                user-authorization-uri="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth"
                token-name="oauth_token"
                client-authentication-scheme="form" />
```

where `client-authentication-scheme` value is `header`.

Comment: Can u be more specific please? i'm new on this.

Did you mean add some like this?
 <clientAuthenticationScheme>
            
        </clientAuthenticationScheme>

Comment: I've added an example in XML. You must edit your spring security file (or create it if not exists) @PauloGaldoSandoval